# String removal inside xargs printf statement?

Tags: bash, find, regular-expression, mv, printf

Currently my `mbsync` is erroring out with a bunch of duplicated `UIDs`. This means I have to find all files that have duplicates of the sub-string `"U=[0-9]+:"` and change the most recent file to remove that sub-string.

For example, a simple case on one file would be:

```
$> fd ".*U=17:.*" --exec ls -la {} \;
-rw-------  1 djm  staff  95903 Mar  2 06:57 cur/1583291317.13980_115.DJM2,U=17:2,ST
-rw-------  1 djm  staff  13654 Sep 30  2015 cur/1580615936.64042_2698.DJM2,U=17:2,S
$> mv ./cur/1583291317.13980_115.DJM2,U=17:2,ST ./cur/1583291317.13980_115.DJM2
```

The problem is, I have about 1000 of these to do. So I'm trying to

1. find all files that have that matching sub-string,
2. sort them by the matching sub-string,
3. show only the duplicate matching files
4. Of those duplicates change the name of the latest file to remove that sub-string.

I'm having trouble finding all the duplicates while keeping the file-path intact to use later when changing the file name.

This is what I have so far:

```
fd ".*U=[0-9]+:.*" | sort -t , -k2.3n | xargs -I{} printf "%s\t${%s//.*,}\n" "{}" "{}"
```

**Note, I'm using the rust utility `fd` similar to `find`.**

I find all the files matching the pattern, I then numerically sort the output split on `,` starting at the third character.

This is where I'm having trouble filtering it down to duplicates as just piping into `uniq -d` gives me nothing because of the file-paths. So I'm thinking, I could `printf` the sub-string spaced away from the file path and then pipe that into `uniq -d`.

I'm not quite sure how to move forward. An answer would inform me how to filter my output down to duplicated file-paths based on the specified sub-string.

Comment: you could add `-u` to the `sort` invocation to pick the first of dupes but that's not guaranteed to be the latest file, it'll be the first among equals as reported by `fd`

Comment: Step 3 and step 4 are getting me confused..  Here is how I would do the first 2 steps. (change date to whatever you need)
`find ./cur/ -type f -newerXY '2020-01-10' | egrep "U=[0-9]*:" | sed 's/,/ /' | awk '{print $2, $1}' | sort -n `

After that command, I would use the output and run it through a for a loop.
`for i in $(ls);do name=$(echo $i|sed 's/,.*//g'); mv $i $name;done`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by adding an extra step thanks to a suggestion by Heysus,

```bsh
x=($(ls -lR ./cur | grep -o 'U=.*:' | sort -k1.3n | uniq -d))

for i in "${x[@]}"; do                                                                                        
  y=$(fd ".*${i}" --exec gstat -c '%X %n' \; | sort -nr | awk 'NR==1,NR==1 {print $2}')
  newy=$(echo "$y" | sed 's/,.*//g')
  mv "$y" "$newy"
done
```